# Time to reconect too fast

Tags: spring-amqp

When rabbit down my listener aplication tries to reconect every 5s. I want it to be able to configure that backoff time. 
Found this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/840, that seams like my problem and "spring guy" said that it was provided a spring property to adjust the value but i cant find that property in the spring docs, btw tested all time related property of ampq and none changed the time. So if anyone can guide me in the write direction ill be listening.
Let me know if you need more data to provide a answer.

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#containerAttributes).

> **reecoveryInterval** Determines the time in milliseconds between attempts to start a consumer if it fails to start for non-fatal reasons. Default: 5000. Mutually exclusive with `recoveryBackOff`.
>
> **recoveryBackOff** Specifies the `BackOff` for intervals between attempts to start a consumer if it fails to start for non-fatal reasons. Default is `FixedBackOff` with unlimited retries every five seconds. Mutually exclusive with `recoveryInterval`.